# .NET 5 MVC Action injection without configuration and FromServices attribute. Why does it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

According to the following microsoft documentation, in order to inject a service in an action method first we need to register it and then we need to inject it into an action method parametre along with the FromServices attribute. I did neither but it's still working. Is it normal?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-injection-with-fromservices

Startup.cs:

```csharp
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

HomeController.cs

```csharp
public IActionResult Index(Random random)
{
    return View(random.Next(100));
}
```

Index.cshtml

```csharp
@model int
Number: @Model
```

Output:

[image]

Edit 1: This question isn't about how dependency injection is done or works. This question is about the understanding the mystery of the situtation explained above. Although I didn't configure anything about Random class, it still injects an instance of Random class.

Comment: What you are doing here isn't Dependency Injection. Create a class that has a property of random (that generates the random number) and then register it.

Comment: Why does it register? Shouldn't it be null or something? And if it's the default behaviour, where is it stated on the official documents?

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is called Model Binding. MVC tries to *model bind* all parameters of action methods. Model binding is used to map data from am HTML form or query string to an object. The model-bound types are typically data-centric objects and there are several constraints to the shape and signature of those objects; typically they require a default constructor.

What you probably like to achieve, however, is called [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/), which means that a dependency (a type that contains *behavior* rather than data) is constructor with its dependencies and injected into a method. These dependencies come from the container, and are configured in the `IServiceCollection`.

To make the distinction whether the parameters should be model bind or injected, MVC forces you to mark injected dependencies with the `[FromService]` attribute.

Both Dependency Injection and Model Binding are two completely different concepts and used for completely different classes in your application. Model Binding for data-centric classes or DTOs, and Dependency Injection for *behavior-centric* objects.

Note that the use of Method Injection in the way that MVC uses it has some downsides. For instance, the built-in DI container contains a feature that is able to check whether all dependencies are registered (which requires to register controllers as services), but any dependency that is method injected into an action will not be considered. This could cause a false sense of security.

Another downside of Method Injection in Controller actions is that it pushes you into a model where controllers can get many dependencies, which is often an indication of a Single Responsibility Principle violation. In other words, Method Injection promotes classes that are big, while you should strive to keep classes small and focused.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but it doesn't specifically address what I asked. I neither posted to the action to be binded as a model nor configured any kind of injection. But it still injects an instance of Random class without any configuration in startup.