# Dependency Injection C# Exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have an asp.net core project I am attempting to use dependency injection in.
However I am getting this exception:

> Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'googleAuthHelperService' parameter a non-null default value.

This is from attempting to inject the interface IGoogleAuthHelperService in to my Controller class:

```
[Route("/auth")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthAsync(IGoogleAuthHelperService googleAuthHelperService)
{

        string response = await GoogleAuthHelperService.ReadHttpBodyAsync(Request.Body);
        string code = GoogleAuthHelperService.ParseGoogleResponseCode(response);
        
        //string code = Request.Body.
        await googleAuthHelperService.GetTokenAsync(code);
        if (response != null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("_Auth");
        }
}
```

```
public interface IGoogleAuthHelperService
{
    public Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string code);
}
public class GoogleAuthHelperService : IGoogleAuthHelperService
{
    private GoogleAuthSettings _settings;
    public GoogleAuthHelperService()
    {
    }
    public GoogleAuthHelperService(IGoogleAuthSettingsService googleAuthSettingsService)
    {
        if (googleAuthSettingsService.Settings != null)
        {
            _settings = googleAuthSettingsService.Settings;
        }
        else
        {
            _settings = new GoogleAuthSettings();
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string code)
    {
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new(_settings.GoogleTokenUrl); // googleauthsettings.token
        _settings.AuthorizationCode = code;
        string content = BuildGoogleTokenBody();
}
public static async Task<string> ReadHttpBodyAsync(Stream stream)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new(stream))
    {
        string content = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see I am injecting a IGoogleAuthSettingsService class into my constructor which is used to get settings from my appsettings.json file:

```
public interface IGoogleAuthSettingsService
{
    public GoogleAuthSettings? Settings {get; }
}
public class GoogleAuthSettingsService : IGoogleAuthSettingsService
{
    public GoogleAuthSettings? Settings { get; set;  }

}
```

Even when I take out the constructor with the IGoogleAuthSettingsService I am recieving the same exception and I am a little lost:

```
public interface IGoogleAuthHelperService
{
    public Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string code);
}
public class GoogleAuthHelperService : IGoogleAuthHelperService
{
    private GoogleAuthSettings _settings;
    public GoogleAuthHelperService()
    {
    }
    public GoogleAuthHelperService(IGoogleAuthSettingsService googleAuthSettingsService)
    {
        if (googleAuthSettingsService.Settings != null)
        {
            _settings = googleAuthSettingsService.Settings;
        }
        else
        {
            _settings = new GoogleAuthSettings();
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string code)
    {
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new(_settings.GoogleTokenUrl); // googleauthsettings.token
        _settings.AuthorizationCode = code;
        string content = BuildGoogleTokenBody();
}
}
```

Here is my program.cs where i register the service as a singleton:

```
using GmailCleaner.Models;
using GmailCleaner.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

IGoogleAuthSettingsService? googleAuthService = builder.Configuration.Get<GoogleAuthSettingsService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoogleAuthSettingsService>(googleAuthService);

GoogleAuthHelperService googleAuthHelperService = new();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoogleAuthHelperService, GoogleAuthHelperService>();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I also tried injecting like this in my Program.cs:

```
GoogleAuthHelperService googleAuthHelperService = new();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoogleAuthHelperService>(googleAuthHelperService);
```

Does anyone know how to fix my class I am injecting?

Comment: @NineBerry, I forgot to add my controller class that the googleAuthHelperService is injected into, one second, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67072969/264697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just use Dependency Injection in an action method in a controller. This would be a security risk. You have two possible solutions:

---

1 **Inject the dependency in the constructor of the controller** and remember it in a private field of the controller class for future use.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGoogleAuthHelperService _googleAuthHelperService;

    public YourController(IGoogleAuthHelperService googleAuthHelperService)
    {
        _googleAuthHelperService = googleAuthHelperService;
    }

    [Route("/auth")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthAsync()
    {
        // Use this._googleAuthHelperService here
    }
```

---

2 Use the **`FromServices` attribute** on the parameter in the action method declaration.

```
[Route("/auth")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthAsync
    ([FromServices] IGoogleAuthHelperService googleAuthHelperService)
{
```

---

See [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection) for more details.

Comment: thanks I will give this a try - I am wondering why there is no error or exception specifying no DI in action method...

Comment: Yup, this works, thanks so much!!